# i cannot find the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SlashCommand')"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This only happens on some commands. Its JS anybody know how to fix it?

```
      };

      let cmd = this.commands.get(command);
      if (cmd.SlashCommand && cmd.SlashCommand.run)
        cmd.SlashCommand.run(this, interaction, args, { GuildDB });
    });
```

Comment: As the error says, `cmd` is `undefined`. Double check what `commands` contains.

Comment: Its all fixed thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try interaction.commandName

**My guess is that there might be some scoping issue utilizing "this"**

If you are using discord.js you likely have client set up in index.js in your base directory, as well as attaching your commands via a command handler. For that reason, the following line will likely work:

```
let cmd = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
```

The reason for this is that index.js declares the "client" as well as "client.commands":

```js
const { Discord, Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField, Permissions, MessageManager, Embed, MessageEmbed, Collection } = require(`discord.js`);
const client = new Client({ allowedMentions: { parse: ['users', 'roles'], repliedUser: true, },intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] }); 

client.commands = new Collection();
```

... and later in index.js you call the command handler, specifying the folder structure your SlashCommand files are in...

```js
    client.handleCommands(commandFolders, "./src/commands");
```

... and your command handler is passed "client" as a prop via an anonymous method/function to populate "client.commands" and "client.commandArray":

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleCommands = async (commandFolders, path) => {
        client.commandArray = [];
        for (folder of commandFolders) {
            const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`${path}/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
            for (const file of commandFiles) {
                const command = require(`../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                client.commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
            }
        }
```

If you utilize "client.commands" you likely will get more standard results.

Comment: Thanks! it's all working well now.